# MongoDB running, but can not connect using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

Sometimes I can get a connection, sometimes it fails

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Wed Jul  3 13:07:09.878 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Wed Jul  3 13:07:09.878 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [1] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
Wed Jul  3 13:07:09.878 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Jul  3 13:07:09.880 JavaScript execution failed: Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Try starting the mongo like this: `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017`.

Comment: @feng, provide mongodb log, please.

Comment: @amezhenin, fund something in log `[initandlisten] pthread_create failed: errno:11 Resource temporarily unavailable
[initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection`, seems to be caused by too many connections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that in MongoDB logs you receive this:

> Wed Jul 3 13:07:... connection refused because too many open connections: 819

Try to do following:

- kill all mongodb processes
- start `mongod`:

  ```
  $ mongod
  ```
- start mongo like bellow:

  ```
  $ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017
  ```